# Why won't my program read input from entry?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
from Tkinter import *
import requests
import base64
var = "lol"
var2 = "lol"
var3 = "111111"
var4 = "31039888252154&31039888252154&0&X168&1411869345&IQSAXYOS&"+var2+"&"+var3+"&&1&3&1&ubugg@zetmail.com&goohoo&1411603529&&2&"
encoded = base64.b64encode(var4)
var5 = encoded




payload = {'X1': '218',
           'X127': 'X325',
           'X171':var,
           'X677':'1420103258',
           'X678':'208180484',
           'X691':var5,
           'X763':'1'}
def bluh(e):
   var = e1.get()
   var2 = e2.get()
   var3 = e3.get()
def Send(e):
    requests.post("http://us23.chatzy.com/", data=payload)
def p1(e):
    print var
    print var2
    print var3

#Sh!t in the GUI
root = Tk()

root.title("Spam Project")
root.geometry("200x200")
app = Frame(root)
app.grid()
button1 = Button(app, text = "Send")
button1.grid()
button1.bind('<Button-1>', Send)


e1 = Entry(root)
e1.grid()
e1.insert(0,"Message")
e2 = Entry(root)
e2.grid()
e2.insert(0,"Name")
e3 = Entry(root)
e3.grid()
e3.insert(0,"Color in Hex")

button2 = Button(app, text = "Submit")
button2.grid()
button2.bind('<Button-1>', bluh)
button3 = Button(app, text = "Print")
button3.grid()
button3.bind('<Button-1>', p1)
var = e1.get()
var2 = e2.get()
var3 = e3.get()

#Event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Basically, what this is supposed to do is take a name, message and hex color and send them as an HTTP request to a chat, this all works in terminal but then I tried to stitch a GUI on top, at the very top, `var`, `var2`, `var3` are all default values and I have the submit button to change those values, but it simply does not work, so I made the "print" button to print the three values and they do not change, can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code and how can I make the three entries change the variables according to what's inside them?

Here's what the variables do.

- var is the message to be sent.
- var2 is the name
- var3 is the color of the message in HEX
- var4 is the string which is part of the request, which is then
  encoded into Base64
- var5 is var4 encoded into Base64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way in GUI code to avoid using globals is to use a class. I hope this isn't too advanced for you. But if it is, well you gotta learn this stuff sometime if you want to do serious programming. :) So read about classes in the Python docs, and then if you still can't figure out what something in my code's doing, ask & I'll try to explain.

I've commented out the actual `requests` stuff for testing purposes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from Tkinter import *
#import requests
import base64


def build_payload(var1, var2, var3):
    var4 = "31039888252154&31039888252154&0&X168&1411869345&IQSAXYOS&" \
        + var2 + "&" + var3 \
        + "&&1&3&1&ubugg@zetmail.com&goohoo&1411603529&&2&"

    print 'var4 = [%s]\n' % var4

    var5 = base64.b64encode(var4)

    payload = {
        'X1': '218',
        'X127': 'X325',
        'X171': var1,
        'X677': '1420103258',
        'X678': '208180484',
        'X691': var5,
        'X763': '1'
    }
    return payload


class my_GUI(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #Build GUI
        root = Tk()

        root.title("Spam Project")
        root.geometry("200x200")

        app = Frame(root)
        app.grid()

        button = Button(app, text = "Send")
        button.grid()
        button.bind('<Button-1>', self.send_data)

        self.e1 = Entry(root)
        self.e1.grid()
        self.e1.insert(0, "Message")

        self.e2 = Entry(root)
        self.e2.grid()
        self.e2.insert(0, "Name")

        self.e3 = Entry(root)
        self.e3.grid()
        self.e3.insert(0, "Color in Hex")

        button = Button(app, text = "Print")
        button.grid()
        button.bind('<Button-1>', self.print_data)

        #Start tkinter event loop
        root.mainloop()


    def print_data(self, e):
        var1 = self.e1.get()
        var2 = self.e2.get()
        var3 = self.e3.get()
        print var1, var2, var3


    def send_data(self,e):
        var1 = self.e1.get()
        var2 = self.e2.get()
        var3 = self.e3.get()
        print var1, var2, var3

        payload = build_payload(var1, var2, var3)
        print 'Sending payload', payload
        #requests.post("http://us23.chatzy.com/", data=payload)


def main():
    my_GUI()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

PS. I've changed the names of some of the functions from what they were in your code, but I've left the variables names (mostly) as they were. In future, try to use more meaningful names - it makes life easier both for yourself & for other people who are trying to read your code.

Comment: Wow, it is hard to believe that is a re-write of my code, I shall study what you wrote and take all lessons I could from it, I will also make sure to use more meaningful names and I will try to learn that "class" magic, thank you so much :D

Comment: No worries, @user3907837. If you like my answer, please feel free to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it. :) Classes might seem strange at first, but they really aren't that hard to understand. Mainly, they just give us a way of tying a bunch of data and functions together in a unit.

Answer (score 1):

To use global variables in Python you need the [`global`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt) statement. So, you need to modify your `bluh` function like this:

```
def bluh(e):
   global var, var2, var3
   var = e1.get()
   var2 = e2.get()
   var3 = e3.get()
```

<sup>(I've also fixed the code to use `e1`, `e2`, `e3` resp. instead of `e1` only)</sup>

In your version you were creating new, local variables `var`, `var2` and `var3` inside the `bluh` function, having nothing to do with the global ones defined at the top of your file. Please also note that in general using global variables is discouraged.

The same goes to the `p1` function, as you also want to access globals.